# Colliding shapes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, game-physics, physics-engine

My plan is to create a "simple" 2-player minigame game (for ex. sumo and race).

My goal would be to efficiently implement collisions (my current code can deal only with simple wall physics and movement of the objects) with square, circle (and triangle?) shaped objects that can be either part of the environment (for ex. "rocks" or immovable obstacles) or part of the user controlled items (for ex. "cars" or pushable obstacles). It would be also nice to know how mass could also be accounted for in the collisions.

There are two aspects I need help with:

1. Different types of dynamic collisions between two moving objects (that have a mass and 2D vector)
   (the physics part not the detection).
2. Making sure everything that needs to collide, collides fast enough (so that my slow computer could still render more than 40-60 frames per second) , and according to the specific rules (or if it would be possible then according to one rule?). So that it would not also be hard to manage the objects that need to be collided (add,  remove, modify and so on).

Or should I just implement two types of collision for ex. static + dynamic circle and dynamic + dynamic circle?

```
def checkcollisions(object1, object2):
    # x is the current x position
    # y is the current y position
    # angle is the current vector angle (calculated from x and y with pythagoros
    # speed is the length of the vector
    dx = object1.x - object2.x
    dy = object1.y - object2.y

    dist = hypot(dx, dy)
    if dist < object1.radius + object2.radius:
        angle = atan2(dy, dx) + 0.5 * pi
        total_mass = object1.mass + object2.mass
        '''''http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/pygame-physics-simulation/mass'''''
        if (0.79 <= object1.angle < 2.36 or 0.79-2*pi <= object1.angle < 2.36-2*pi) or (3.93 <= object1.angle < 5.5 or 3.93-2*pi <= object1.angle < 5.5-2*pi) and ((0.79 <= object2.angle < 2.36 or 0.79-2*pi <= object2.angle < 2.36-2*pi) or (3.93 <= object2.angle < 5.5 or 3.93-2*pi <= object2.angle < 5.5-2*pi)):
            (object2angle, object2speed) = vectorsum((object2.angle, object2.speed*(object2.mass-object1.mass)/total_mass), (angle+pi, 2*object1.speed*object1.mass/total_mass))
            (object1angle, object1speed) = vectorsum((object1.angle, object1.speed*(object1.mass-object2.mass)/total_mass), (angle, 2*object2.speed*object2.mass/total_mass))
        else:
            '''''https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision'''''
            CONTACT_ANGLE = angle
            x = (((object1.speed * cos(object1.angle - CONTACT_ANGLE) * (object1.mass-object2.mass)+ 2*object2.mass*object2.speed*cos(object2.angle - CONTACT_ANGLE))/total_mass)*cos(CONTACT_ANGLE))+object1.speed*sin(object1.angle - CONTACT_ANGLE)*cos(CONTACT_ANGLE + 0.5 * pi)
            y = (((object1.speed * cos(object1.angle - CONTACT_ANGLE) * (object1.mass-object2.mass)+ 2*object2.mass*object2.speed*cos(object2.angle - CONTACT_ANGLE))/total_mass)*cos(CONTACT_ANGLE))+object1.speed*sin(object1.angle - CONTACT_ANGLE)*sin(CONTACT_ANGLE + 0.5 * pi)
            object1angle = pi/2 - atan2(y, x)
            object1speed = hypot(x, y)

            x = (((object2.speed * cos(object2.angle - CONTACT_ANGLE)*(object2.mass-object1.mass)+2*object1.mass*object1.speed*cos(object1.angle - CONTACT_ANGLE))/total_mass)*cos(CONTACT_ANGLE))+object2.speed*sin(object2.angle - CONTACT_ANGLE)*cos(CONTACT_ANGLE + 0.5 * pi)
            y = (((object2.speed * cos(object2.angle - CONTACT_ANGLE)*(object2.mass-object1.mass)+2*object1.mass*object1.speed*cos(object1.angle - CONTACT_ANGLE))/total_mass)*cos(CONTACT_ANGLE))+object2.speed*sin(object2.angle - CONTACT_ANGLE)*sin(CONTACT_ANGLE + 0.5 * pi)
            object2angle = pi/2 - atan2(y, x)
            object2speed = hypot(x, y)

        (object2.angle, object2.speed) = (object2angle, object2speed)
        (object1.angle, object1.speed) = (object1angle, object1speed)
        object1.speed *= 0.999
        object2.speed *= 0.999

        overlap = 0.5*(object1.radius + object2.radius - dist+1)
        object1.x += sin(angle)*overlap
        object1.y -= cos(angle)*overlap
        object2.x -= sin(angle)*overlap
        object2.y += cos(angle)*overlap

'''''http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/pygame-physics-simulation/mass'''''


def vectorsum(vectorx, vectory):  # Every array's first number is the degree from 0, the second is speed
    x = sin(vectory[0]) * vectory[1] + sin(vectorx[0]) * vectorx[1]
    y = cos(vectory[0]) * vectory[1] + cos(vectorx[0]) * vectorx[1]  # Calculating new vectors from anle and lenght
    angle = pi / 2 - atan2(y, x)  # Calculating the degree
    speed = hypot(x, y)  # Calculating the speed
    return angle, speed
```

(I'm just a beginner with Python (or English) so keep that in mind please.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Collision detection is very easy in pygame. Take a look at using [pygame.sprite](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html).  They have several functions to detect collisions. ([spritecollide](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide), [groupcollide](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide), etc)  If you have some complex collision interaction generally you use the rect or circle to see if they collide, then only do your complex calculations on those.  Though for most games you do not need to have the cost of perfect collision detection, close enough is good enough.
2. As far was what happens when you collide, that is more physics then programming. Some concepts to keep in mind are: momentum conservation, elastic vs inelastic collisions, deflection angle.  "How to building a 2D physics engine" is a bit too broad for SO question. Maybe look at [how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-oriented-rigid-bodies](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-oriented-rigid-bodies--gamedev-8032)

Comment: Indeed collision detection is easy, but the collision part itself is not plus iterating through all the objects I will have would be I quess too slow (on a slow computer) . That's what I need help with, I'll try to make my question clearer.

Comment: @Avamander  I think more specifics would be good here.  How many collideable object are there? How many are likely to be moving at one time?  What type of collision are you trying to model?  How should the different collideable objects behave when hit?

Comment: 1-50 (100 maximum) objects. Half of the objects would moving at once. I am trying to model elastic collision. The objects should collide as realistic as possible according to their mass and velocity (I doubt that size matters). Basically, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision, but in python and with not only circles. I also posted the current way I managed to get working with two circles.

Comment: The current code is hideous but one half (the tutorial one) works with collisions from the sides and the other half (the wikipedia formula) works with collisions from top and bottom. The formulas are a bit too complex for me to fix or find the error and the current functions do not care about squares and triangles.

Comment: Any ideas how I could improve my existing code or create better?

Comment: Dont pass the combination of every object to that function.  Use `Sprite.groupcollide` to find possible collisions first.

Comment: Yes, I am passing every combination to that function.

Comment: "pygame.sprite.groupcollide() Collision is determined by comparing the Sprite.rect attribute of each Sprite or by using the collided function if it is not None." I don't have a rect attribute of each sprite, I have the radius of the sprite.

Comment: All sprites and in fact everything you draw on a surface has a rect.  Your circle with a radius lives inside the rect.  Nothing can collide without colliding with the rect colliding as well.  Since rect collision detection is very fast and cheap, do that first.  Only if the rects collide do you need to check if the actual objects collide.

Comment: Indeed, I must now make the necessary changes.